# Angular 4 ignoring media queries

Tags: css, angular, sass

I don't know why angular is ignoring media query. For example:

```
.app-body {
    app-navigation {
        nav a {
            font-size: 18px;
            width: 100rem;
        }
    }
}
```

Should compile to:

```
.app-body app-navigation nav a {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 100rem; }
```

And it dont overwrite:

nav[_ngcontent-c2] a[_ngcontent-c2]

Thanks.

Comment: file extension to which you are writing, having extension .scss/.sass ???

Comment: have you created the angular project with --scss build ??? I mean every style file will have  .scss extension

Comment: styles is compiled properly, but chrome takes nav[_ngcontent-c2] a[_ngcontent-c2] styles not the .app-body...

Comment: Is `app-navigation` a class or an HTML element? And is `.app-body` a class or an element? (same question for `nav`)

Comment: app-navigation - class, rest html